# Python Caesar Cypher analysing an input file

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I am trying to create a Caesar Cypher function where when given an input file the program (via command line) analyses the file finding out how many of each letter (both lower and upper case) are present. From there i can figure out the key to decrypt the file.

The problem i am having is pulling the most common letter where i can then convert it into a key.

My code below is far from complete. I have been trying to find a way to pull the most common letter. From there i believe using variations of code already used i will be able to convert and use a number as a key. I really just need a pointer on how to get the initial character.

This code is not the complete program, only the code that has been used to analyse the file and store the results in a Dictionary:

```
elif fileOption == "2":
def decryptChars(aString):
    "Function to count characters in the input file"
    charCount = {}
    for char in aString:
        if char in charCount.isalpha():
            if char in charCount:
                charCount[char] = charCount[char] + 1
            else:
                charCount[char] = 1
        return charCount

try:
    inputFile = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
except:
    sys.exit("The file {} could not be opened...".format(sys.argv[1]))

totalChars = inputFile.read().replace(" ", "")

charCount = decryptChars(totalChars)
print(sorted(charCount.items()))
```

When i pass a file with the string "Rather than requiring all the desired functionality to be built into the language's core" i get the result:

```
[('R', 1), ('a', 6), ('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 2), ('e', 9), ('f', 1), ('g', 3), ('h', 4), ('i', 7), ('l', 5), ('n', 6), ('o', 4), ('q', 1), ('r', 5), ('s', 2), ('t', 9), ('u', 4), ('y', 1)]
```

(I know not the best test piece as it will return 2 with 9...).

Any advice would be hugely helpful.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Given the list of tuples you showed at the end of your question, which is a list of letter-frequency pairs, you would like to pick the most frequent letter?

Comment: The result seems fine, except that it considers `R` and `r` as 2 different characters. Is that the only problem?

Comment: @user3030010 Correct. I need to identify the most frequent letter and then use that as the key. I just cannot find a way to grab the most frequesnt key automatically.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I need them seperate, as this can affect the key.

Comment: Side-note: Caesar shifts can be accomplished efficiently and trivially with `str.translate`. Create a translation table up front (with `string.maketrans` from `string` module on Py2, `str.maketrans` on Py3), then use the `str.translate` method to run a string through it, returning the translated string.

Comment: @ShadowRanger in an ideal world, but for this assignment we are expected to work around it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

```
charCount = {'R': 1, 'a': 6, 'b': 2...}
```

here's a one-liner to get the char with most occurrences:

```
max(charCount, key=charCount.get)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like exactly what i need.
Where you have 'sample' as the  dictionary name is that equal to the charCount dictionary? Or would i have to redefine it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that this list of tuples is actually result of your `sorted(charCount.items())`. Please see updated answer then, it's even simpler.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have implemented this and it appears to be running with no errors. Though i am unable to call the key (for example when i try to print the key it says it has not been defined). I thought `...key=charCount.get...` was defining the key.

Comment: By putting `key =` in front of `max(...` i have resolved that. I dont know if this is a bad workaround though.

Comment: Thank you man. I've just finished the code with this implemented. It works perfectly! As long as the highest frequency is the lowercasse e equivelant. And thats good enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

Alright given your list that contains the pairs:

```
l = [('R', 1), ('a', 6), ...]
```

The simplest way to do this would be with a for loop

```
char = ''
freq = 0
for new_char, new_freq in l:
    if new_freq > freq:
        freq = new_freq
        char = new_char
```